# The law of large number of minimum i.i.d variables random

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

Note that from https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-21/issue-3/Limit-of-the-Smallest-Eigenvalue-of-a-Large-Dimensional-Sample/10.1214/aop/1176989118.full

Let $\{x_{ij}\;|\;i,j=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a double array of i. i.  d. random variables and let $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, $\beta\ge 0$ and $M>0$ be constants. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \max_{i\le Mn^\beta}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{ij}-m}{n^\alpha}\right|\to 0\ a.s.\ (n\to\infty)
\iff
E|x_{11}|^{\frac{1+\beta}{\alpha}}< \infty\ \&
\  m=\begin{cases}\displaystyle
E x_{11},&(\alpha\le 1),\\
\displaystyle\text{any},&(\alpha>1).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Suppose that $n,p\to\infty$ with $p/n\to c>0$. I am confuse that how to derive law large number from i. i. d $x_j,x_{ij}\sim N_p(0,1)$. I mean I want to derive
\begin{align*}
\min_{i\le p}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{ij}^2}{n}\to 1\; a.s.\;\text{and}\;\min_{i\le p}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_jx_{ij}}{n}\to 0\; a.s.
\end{align*}

What is $M$ to derive the above convergence?

Thank you in advance.